# factorial function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, function, loops

This a simple code for factorial, I have written the function and it loops through giving right output but at the end, it returns undefined. I don't know why.

```
function factorial(n){
    let value=1; 
    for(let i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        value = i*value; 
        console.log(value); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: There's no `return` statement, so `undefined` gets returned...

Answer (score 3):

Because you do not return anything from the function, so `undefined` is the result of its work. 
You need to return the value explicitly:

```
function factorial(n){
  let value=1;

  for(let i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    value = i*value; 
    console.log(value); 
  } 

  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find factorial by using recursion. Here is the implementation.

```js
    function factorial(x){
         if(x == 0)  //Exit condition
             return 1;
         return x * factorial(x-1);  //5*4*3*2*1
    }
    
    console.log(factorial(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is good implementation:

```
const factorial = n => n > 1 ? n * factorial(--n) : 1;
```

And your function does not have `return`, so it returns `undefined`;